# How to open a modal window inside a modal window

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nsapplication

This code is called when a button is pressed in a modal window.
The current window was made modal by using [NSApp runModalForWindow:[self window]] inside -(void)showWindow:(id)sender method.

To open the new window I use the following code. It works ok, but the button that was pressed, stays in a "clicked" state. So probably I'm doing something wrong.

```
- (IBAction)restoreFrom:(id)sender {
    __block RestoreBackupController *restoreController = [[RestoreBackupController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"RestoreBackup"];



    [restoreController setWindowWillCloseBlock:^{
        [restoreController autorelease];

        [restoreController.window orderOut:self];
        [NSApp runModalForWindow:self.window];
    }
     ];

    [NSApp runModalForWindow:restoreController.window];
}
```

The block gets called by a subclass of NSWindowController when receiving the close message.
Thank you.